# Specify the number of next?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple identical classes with the save properties so I cannot use `nextUntil()`.

Let say I want to get the third one. How can I do that with the `next()` function?
`[index]` does not work.

```
<div class="order-modifier-list"> </div>
<div class="order-modifier-list"> </div>
<div class="order-modifier-list"> </div>
<div class="order-modifier-list"> </div>
```

```js
$(`.order-modifier-list`).next().find(`.order-modifier-list-item[item-id=${itemID}]`).attr('data-modifier-details')
```

Comment: If you want to retrieve an element by its index use `:eq()`: `$('.order-modifier-list:eq(2)')` will do what you require. It's not entirely clear what you're asking though, or why you feel you need to use `next()` at all

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`next()` is not meant for getting the element by specifying index or number. The purpose of `next` is to get the next sibling of selected element. If you want to specify the number then use `.eq()`, which will return you a jQuery object of a specified element.

```js
console.log($('.order-modifier-list').eq(2));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="order-modifier-list">1 </div>
<div class="order-modifier-list">2 </div>
<div class="order-modifier-list">3 </div>
<div class="order-modifier-list">4 </div>
```